# How would I create and manage a .txt file with Terminal

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite

How would I create a `.txt` file, customize what it says, and open it. All with Terminal. [OSX Yosemite]

Comment: if you get answers, choose the right answer & kindly up-vote them if they are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For personal use (ie, not in scripts) I recommend `nano`. A somewhat controversial choice among frequent terminal users, but unlike `vi`and `vim`, `nano` isn't modal (ie, it's going to work the way you would expect a graphical text editor to work). Using `nano` will let you perform all three actions (create the file, edit the text, and view it) all with one command. Your syntax will be `nano /path/to/file.txt`. Of course, you can also use `vi` or `vim`, but if you choose to you definitely need to read about *how* first (if you're coming from a graphical background you've almost certainly never even heard of a modal editor before).

To create the file without opening the editor, use `touch`. This creates an empty file. The syntax would be `touch /path/to/file.txt`. If you need to make  a new folder to put the file in, use `mkdir`. The syntax is `mkdir /path/to`.

To view the file without opening the editor, use `cat` (syntax `cat /path/to/file.txt`) if it's short. This will just print the whole file to the terminal. If the file is longer, use `less` or `more`, which will each allow some navigation (eg, they'll let you scroll). By this point, you can probably guess the syntax. They're very similar commands: more or less, `less` is `more`, but more (`less` lets you scroll backward, `more` does not). Of course, you can also just look at the file in `nano` and then not write any changes.

Finally, if you `cd` into your working directory first, you can just refer to the file with its name without the path (eg, `nano file.txt`, and similar for the other commands I mentioned). It stands for "current directory" and the syntax is `cd /path/to`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using Vim editor:

```
`vi text.txt` would create a file.
You may edit it and save it use `[Esc]:wq`
```

Using cat command:

```
cat > file.txt <<EOF
>some text
>to save
>EOF
```

Using redirection:

```
echo "Some text here." > file.txt
```

Comment: it even makes scripts more readable to have a bunch of  echo commands, one per line of the txt file of  `echo "this is the next line in the file" >> file.txt`

Comment: @infixed yes. But I like `cat` the most.. fastest one for small files.

Answer (score 1):

There are several text editors that come with terminal on OS X.  VI, emacs, and nano are probably the most well known.

Try running `man nano`, `man vi`, and `man emacs` or just googling those three items as well as 'OS X Terminal Text Editor' to learn more about them.

They will give you the ability to create files, name files, save files, and edit existing files.